# C linker error with gcc and math.h

Tags: c, gcc, linker, math.h, trigonometry

I am getting an error stating `pythagorean.so: undefined symbol: cos`. I am compiling with the `math.h`, `stdlib.h`, and `stdio.h` libraries and the `-lm` switch. Here a code snippet:

```
static bool
law_of_cosine_run(esh_command* cmd)
{
    if (strcmp(cmd->argv[0], "lawofcosine") == 0) {
        printf("The length of the third side is: %f\n", 
        law_of_cosine(strtol(cmd->argv[1], NULL, 10), 
        strtol(cmd->argv[2], NULL, 10), strtol(cmd->argv[3], NULL, 10)));       
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static double
law_of_cosine(double x, double y, double z)
{
    return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) - (2 * x * y * cos(z)));
}
```

Does anyone know why this would occur? pythagorean.c is my .c file.

Thanks

Comment: Did you put the `-lm` before or after all source and object files? It needs to be after.

Answer (score 3):

When you compile it make sure you type

```
gcc *.c -lm
```